# Libc name and compilers

Tags: gcc, operating-system, compiler-specific

I apologize if the question is trivial, but I have googled around and downloaded the gcc source code too without finding a satisfactory answer.

So, how the compiler ( gcc/clang/etc... ) knows the file name of the libc? I know that unix-like systems name it libc.a, libc.so, etc... But, for example, mac os x names it libSystem. I suppose the name is hardcoded in the code of the compiler, but I have found no evidence yet.

Comment: Let me tell you about a very useful tool: `grep`. Applying it to the gcc sources would tell you that `gcc/config/darwin.h` contains the string `-lSystem`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

C Library linkage flag is hard coded in source code of gcc, grep `-lc` or `-lSystem` in source code of gcc. On compilation, gcc searchs for libc with name `libc.so` or `libc.a` in its search path ( add prefix `lib` and suffix `.so` or `.a`)

Below is some result from `grep '\-lc' -r ./gcc/config/` under gcc source code directory.

```
......
./gcc/config/i386/sysv5.h:  %{!shared:%{!symbolic:-lc -lcrt}}"
```

Result of `grep '\-lSystem' -r ./gcc/config/`

```
./gcc/config/darwin.h:#define LIB_SPEC "%{!static:-lSystem}"
```